# Year Month Day to Decimal year conversion in octave

Tags: octave

I have a time series data in a Year, Month and day format. Now I want to convert it to a decimal year format. How to do it in octave.

Any clue

Comment: have a look: https://wiki.octave.org/Date/Time_functions

Answer (score 0):

Thy this

```
DateString = {'09/16/2007';'05/14/1996';'11/29/2010'};
formatIn = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
datenum(DateString,formatIn)
```

For more info : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html